# display array in gap

Tags: excel, vba

In this example, I define an array StudentName of five strings using the Dim keyword. I include an InputBox to accept input from the user. I also use the For ...Next loop to accept the input five times and display the five names from cell A1 to cell E1. The code is as follows:

```
 Sub CommandButton1_Click( )

Dim StudentName(1 to 5) As String
For i = 1 To 5
StudentName(i) = InputBox("Enter student Name")
Cells(i, 1) = StudentName(i)
Next
End Sub
```

How I display those 5 names in GAP OF 10 CELLS :A30 to A40 to A50 and so on?

Comment: Not clear what is expected output, could you please manually populate the worksheet as needed, make a screenshot of it, upload and share the link?

Answer (score 0):

Change your array dimensions to a zero-based one and use the iteration var (`i`) as a multiplier.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click( )
    Dim StudentName(0 to 4) As String

    For i = lbound(StudentName) To ubound(StudentName)
        StudentName(i) = InputBox("Enter student Name")
        Cells(30 + i * 10, 1) = StudentName(i)
    Nexti

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you were very helpful